# Getting Undefined local variable or method `brown' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I am trying to write a simple ruby script using a method that would call a value from hash but I keep getting the following error:

> Undefined local variable or method `brown' for main:Object (NameError)

What can be done to fix this code?

```
brown = {
'1' => 'tv',
'2' => 'radio'
}

def door(name)
   puts brown[name]
end

door('1')
```

Comment: If you move the definition of the hash `brown` into the method definition, before `puts brown[name]`, it works fine. Does that tell you something? Also, doesn't your error message refer to `brown`, not `hush_brown`?

Comment: Carry, thanks for the response. How can i move the definition of the hash into the method? And yes it supposed to be just  "brown"

Comment: `def door(name); brown = { '1'=>'tv', '2'=>'radio' }; puts brown[name]; end`. Then `door('1') #=> 'tv'`. This is about "scope". See [this](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/localvars.html) for a short discussion of the scope of local variables (like `brown`). The scope of instance variables is different, which is why your code would work if `brown` were an instance variable (`@brown`).

Comment: thank you for clarifying the "scope". I fixed the code!

Answer (score 1):

brown is local variable and it's not at the same context than door function, try this

```
@brown = { 
  '1' => 'tv',
  '2' => 'radio'
}

def door(name)
     puts @brown[name]
end

door('1')
```

or this

```
brown = { 
  '1' => 'tv',
  '2' => 'radio'
}

def door(name,brown)
     puts brown[name]
end

door('1',brown)
```

Comment: For your second option, you'll need to add brown as a second argument to the method definition of door: 

def door( name, brown )

Answer (score 0):

You can just define the brown hash as a method:

```
def brown 
  {
  '1' => 'tv',
  '2' => 'radio'
  }
end

def door(name)
   puts brown[name]
end

door('1')
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution.